# Interseção entre mesma tabela, auto relacionamento, mysql com INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, auto-incremento, inner-join

Olá, estou fazendo um banco de dados clone facebook. Tenho duas tabelas, uma de usuários e outra amizade. A tabela amizades é um auto relacionamento de usuários como mostra a imagem.

[image: Foto modelo]

Esta tabela de amizades contém os IDs de cada usuário e preciso selecionar as amizades em comum entre dois usuários selecionados.
Por exemplo:

`| idUsuario1    | idUsuario2    |
| ------------- | ------------- |
| 1.            | 2.            |
| 2.            | 3.            |
| 2.            | 4.            |
| 1.            | 3.            |`

Preciso buscar nesta tabela os amigos comuns de usuario1 e usuario2. Ou seja, o retorno será 3,4. Porém não estou conseguindo filtrar corretamente a saida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja a querie abaixo, ele liga as amizades do usuario 1 com as do usuario 2 e trás apenas os usuários das intersecções:

```
select u.* 
from amizade a1, amizade a2 , usuario u
where  a1.idUsuario2 =  a2.idUsuario2 
    and u.id  =  a1.idUsuario2
    and a1.idUsuario1  = 1 --id do primeiro usuario
    and a2.idUsuario1  = 2 --id do segundo usuario
```